# OSMNX: different results when searching for cycleways with custom_filter and df.apply

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am searching for the total length of cycleways in different cities.

By doing so, I came across something which I can't explain:

With this method...

```
city = "Karlsruhe, Germany"
graph = ox.graph_from_place(city, network_type="bike", custom_filter='["highway"~"cycleway"]')
cycleways = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=False, edges=True)
length = cycleways["length"].sum()/1000
print(length)
```

... I receive a total length of about 23 km.
Whereas with this method...

```
city = "Karlsruhe, Germany"
graph = ox.graph_from_place(city, network_type="bike")
cycleways = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=False, edges=True)
contains_cycleway = cycleways["highway"].apply(lambda value: "cycleway" in str(value))
cycleways = cycleways[contains_cycleway]
length = cycleways["length"].sum()/1000
print(length)
```

... the total length is about 109 km.

I saved the df as excel and did som manual filtering and adding. So I found out, that with the first method only cycleways tagged with more than one tag in an array (e.g ['cycleway', 'service']) are counted, but not those only tagged with "cycleway". The second method counts both.

Even though I am fine with my recent task, I might need the custom_filter one day and would like to know what I did wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code snippets aren't complete and reproducible, so it's impossible to assess. If you make them standalone and runnable, we may be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: I edited the code in the question to make it standalone. I also looked if this effect appears with "Paris, France" and "New York City, New York, USA", too. It does.